# Paste found value alongside text - Excel formula

Tags: excel, formula

`=IFERROR(LEFT(B9,FIND(" ",B6)),B6)`

So currently this returns the first word found in a cells string.

It works as intended on that part but for example if it returned `Apple` in the cell I wish to paste it in.

How would I add my text alongside it?

For example, I want it to paste `My Apple` and not just the value found which would just be `Apple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want add extra word then just concatenate it either by `CONCATENATE()` formula or concatenate operator `&`. Try-

```
="My " & IFERROR(LEFT(B9,FIND(" ",B6)),B6)
```